# Compare values of two objects using nested for loops and return an array of modified objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, assign

I have two arrays of objects:

```
const testArr1 = [
      {
        event: "Ryan's birthday",
        time: "4:00",
      },
      {
        event: "Steves's birthday",
        time: "2:00",
      },
      {
        event: "Helen's birthday",
        time: "1:00",
      },
      {
        event: "Paola's birthday",
        time: "3:00",
      },
      {
        event: "Jared's birthday",
        time: "9:00",
      },
    ];
```

and

```
const testArr2 = [
      {
        time: "4:00",
        temp: 41,
      },
      {
        time: "6:00",
        temp: 42,
      },
      {
        time: "8:00",
        temp: 43,
      },
      {
        time: "1:00",
        temp: 44,
      },
      {
        time: "3:00",
        temp: 45,
      },
      {
        time: "9:00",
        temp: 46,
      },
    ];
```

I would like to create a function that takes these two arrays of objects and returns a new array of objects called `dataToDisplay`.  `dataToDisplay` should contain objects related to events.

I want the function `getDataToDisplay` to see if an event has temperature data available by comparing `testArr1` and `testArr2` values at the `time` key, and then give me an array of objects that either have pertinent `temp` data when `time` values match, or have `no matching data found` noted when `time` values do not match.

My problem is that, using the function as I've built it now, an object is getting pushed to `dataToDisplay` in *every* iteration that returns false when comparing the time values, so there is a lot of duplicate data.

Here is the function:

```
const getDataToDisplay = (testArr1, testArr2) => {
  const dataToDisplay = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < testArr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < testArr2.length; j++) {
      let objToPush = {};

      //if times in both objects are equal, push an object containing event, time, and temp value at that time to dataToDisplay
      //break and move on if times are equal
      if (testArr1[i].time === testArr2[j].time) {
        Object.assign(objToPush, {
          event: testArr1[i].event,
          time: testArr1[i].time,
          temp: testArr2[j].temp,
        });
        dataToDisplay.push(objToPush);
        break;
      } else {
        //if times in both objects are NOT equal, push an object containing event, time, and a temp value of "no matching data found"
        Object.assign(objToPush, {
          event: testArr1[i].event,
          time: testArr1[i].time,
          temp: "no matching data found",
        });
        //this is pushing an object every time the condition returns false
        //I only want one object returned if false
        dataToDisplay.push(objToPush);
      }
    }
  }
  return dataToDisplay;
};
```

here is what happens when the function is called

```
console.log(getDataToDisplay(testArr1, testArr2));
    //logs
    //     [
    //   {
    //     "event": "Ryan's birthday",
    //     "time": "4:00",
    //     "temperature": 41
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "event": "Steves's birthday",
    //     "time": "2:00",
    //     "temperature": "no matching data found"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "event": "Steves's birthday",
    //     "time": "2:00",
    //     "temperature": "no matching data found"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     "event": "Steves's birthday",
    //     "time": "2:00",
    //     "temperature": "no matching data found"
    //   }
    //   ...
    // ]

    //but I want it to log something like this
    // [
    //   {
    //     event: "Ryan's birthday",
    //     time: "4:00",
    //     temperature: 41,
    //   },
    //   {
    //     event: "Steves's birthday",
    //     time: "2:00",
    //     temperature: "no matching data found",
    //   },
    //   {
    //     event: "Helen's birthday",
    //     time: "1:00",
    //     temperature: 44,
    //   },
    //   ...
    // ];
```

How do I just return one new modified object per event, rather than the result of every one of the comparisons? I feel like I'm so close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and go over each object in `testArr1` and find the object with matching `temp` in `testArr2` using `Array.prototype.find`. If matched combine both else populate "no matching records found":

```js
const testArr1 = [{ event: "Ryan's birthday", time: "4:00" }, { event: "Steves's birthday", time: "2:00" }, { event: "Helen's birthday", time: "1:00" }, { event: "Paola's birthday", time: "3:00" }, { event: "Jared's birthday", time: "9:00" }],
testArr2 = [{ time: "4:00", temp: 41 }, { time: "6:00", temp: 42 }, { time: "8:00", temp: 43 }, { time: "1:00", temp: 44 }, { time: "3:00", temp: 45 }, { time: "9:00", temp: 46 }];

const getDataToDisplay = (testArr1, testArr2) => {
  const defaultText =  "no matching records found";
  return testArr1.reduce((acc, p) => {
    const matchingTime = testArr2.find(t => t.time === p.time);
    const temperature = (matchingTime && matchingTime.temp) || defaultText;
    acc.push({...p, temperature});
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(getDataToDisplay(testArr1, testArr2));
```

The issue with your approach is you are comparing the object from the outer for-loop with every object in the inner for-loop. You only need to find a object which has the same time in the second array `testArr2` if not found add the message  "no matching records found".

But in your case the inner loop is pushing a new object in the output array every time there is a mismatch with the `time` property.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for all times of the `temparatures` array and map the `events` array with the values of `times` object by using `time` as key.

```js
const
    noData = 'no matching data found',
    events = [{ event: "Ryan's birthday", time: "4:00" }, { event: "Steves's birthday", time: "2:00" }, { event: "Helen's birthday", time: "1:00" }, { event: "Paola's birthday", time: "3:00" }, { event: "Jared's birthday", time: "9:00" }],
    temperatures = [{ time: "4:00", temp: 41 }, { time: "6:00", temp: 42 }, { time: "8:00", temp: 43 }, { time: "1:00", temp: 44 }, { time: "3:00", temp: 45 }, { time: "9:00", temp: 46 }],
    times = Object.fromEntries(temperatures.map(({ time, temp }) => [time, temp])),
    result = events.map(o => ({ ...o, temperature: times[o.time] || noData }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```